# Jquery step wizard in conflict with Image Uploader

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

From this [**Jquery Step form**](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples#basic-form) I have a conflict with the image uploader. Where people can upload the avatar when he creating a account. From now, every inputbox, is working. It's saving information to the databse.

Only the upload form/box isn't working. I'm not getting errors in the console, however, if i remove the script from Jquery Step form then the upload from is working.

This is the script:

```
(function ($)
{
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        var form = $("#djForm");
        form.validate({
            errorPlacement: function errorPlacement(error, element) { element.before(error); },
            rules: {
                confirm: {
                    equalTo: "#password"
                }
            }
        });
        form.children("div").steps({
            headerTag: "h3",
            bodyTag: "section",
            transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
            onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex)
            {
                // Allways allow step back to the previous step even if the current step is not valid!
                if (currentIndex > newIndex)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
                return form.valid();
            },
            onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex)
            {
                form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";
                return form.valid();
            },

            onFinished: function (event, currentIndex)
            {
                alert("Submitted!");
            }
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

I use this because without it, it would not work.

```
(function ($)
{
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {

    });

})(jQuery);
```

Someone need to help me with this.

Comment: Can you please share your HTML code as well? ;)

Comment: The code is based on PHP/HTML and has over 1000+ lines in code. These all is inside the <form> Is it necessary that I post this anyway?